# Setting variables of a class within another in Java

Tags: java, class, variables

I have two classes in my main class(lets call them classA and classB).

Is there any chance to set classA variables within classB?

Something like that:

```
class classB {
    int indexB;

    classB() {
        indexB = 0;
        classA.index = indexB;
    }
}
```

thank you very much!
greetings

Comment: Please specify the language, by using a tag and mentioning it in your question.

Comment: Do you really mean "in your main class"? I think you mean in your source file - the .java file. You might be using inner classes but that is a more advanced technique.

Comment: @geomanagas : `java` is tagged with question

Comment: @rkp yes but look at the timestamp on his comment and then look at the editing history. It was not tagged when he made that comment. Please pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can directly assign `public` variables of `classA` as you did in your snippet, or declare a setter for `private` variables.-

**classA**

```
public setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}
```

**classB**

```
classAInstance.setIndex(indexB);
```

Comment: yes, but it needs to be an instance (as implied above), or you need to declare the variable static, but that is not very OOP-like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Assuming `index` of the class `classA` is also package protected and `classA` is in the same package as `classB` then you can do something like that:

```
class classA {
    int index;
    classA() {}
    // OR
    classA(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
}

class classB {
    int indexB;
    classA classA;

    classB() {
        indexB = 0;

        classA = new classA();
        classA.index = indexB;
        // OR 
        classA = new classA(indexB);
    }
}
```

If both classes are in different packages you then you need a public setter for `index` in `classA` as demonstrated by ssantos (The second method I've shown, using the constructor, will work in this case too it the constructor is public).

It is however not very good to access members of other classes directly. Please use getters and setters for that, also please consider the java naming conventions: class should start with an uppercase letter, thus `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

Answer (score 0):

The index has to be a static variable of class A.Then you can do this.